# unable to use package-info. javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class XXX do not have a property of the name {YYY}document

Tags: java, javax.xml

short: Is it possible to change classes in my package test (add some headers) so I don't have to use packege-info.java?

longer version:
In eclipse my program works fine. But after convertion to exe with commercial encrypting program I am getting error.

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class test.xsd.SendDocument do not have a property of the name {https://YYY/xsd}document
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.BodyBuilder$DocLit.<init>(BodyBuilder.java:191)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIMethodHandler.<init>(SEIMethodHandler.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.<init>(SyncMethodHandler.java:73)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:71)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:628)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:331)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:313)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:295)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:92)
    at test.GateService.getGateServiceSOAP12Port(GateService.java:74)
    at com.myprogram.model.sign.Declar2TestWS.<init>(Declar2TestWS.java:108)
    at com.myprogram.sap.jco.server.SAPServerConnection$SignXMLFunctionHandler.createWS(SAPServerConnection.java:393)
    at com.myprogram.sap.jco.server.SAPServerConnection$SignXMLFunctionHandler.handleRequest(SAPServerConnection.java:284)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultServerWorker$FunctionDispatcher.handleRequest(DefaultServerWorker.java:1009)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultServerWorker$FunctionDispatcher.handleRequest(DefaultServerWorker.java:937)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultServerWorker.dispatchRequest(DefaultServerWorker.java:153)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.MiddlewareJavaRfc$JavaRfcServer.dispatchRequest(MiddlewareJavaRfc.java:3300) 
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.MiddlewareJavaRfc$JavaRfcServer.listen(MiddlewareJavaRfc.java:2350)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultServerWorker.dispatch(DefaultServerWorker.java:277)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultServerWorker.loop(DefaultServerWorker.java:337)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultServerWorker.run(DefaultServerWorker.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: {https://YYY/xsd}document is not a valid property on class test.xsd.SendDocument
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBContextImpl.java:931)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.BodyBuilder$DocLit.<init>(BodyBuilder.java:188)
    ... 21 more
```

**I manage to get the same error in eclipse by deleting `packege-info.java`
packege-info.java:**

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "https://YYY/xsd", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)

package test;
```

Is it possible to change classes in my package test (add some headers) so I don't have to use packege-info.java?

Thank you for the help!